# Applying CSS to force:recordView in lightning:component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

I'm trying to use `force:recordView` and it works okay in Lightning Experience, and S1 but but when rendered in a stand alone app, the SLDS CSS are not applied - that is if I preview the **sampleViewRecordApp.app** as a stand alone app the page does not have the SLDS CSS styling.

**sampleViewRecordApp.app**

```
<aura:application implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess" extends="force:slds">
    <c:sampleViewRecord />
</aura:application>
```

**sampleViewRecord.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <force:recordView recordId="001A0000002GcNXIA0" />

</aura:component>
```